# Obtener elementos comunes de dos listas sin repeticiones

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que implementar el siguiente enunciado:

> Diseña una función que reciba dos listas y devuelva elementos comunes a
>   ambos, sin repetir ninguno (intersección de conjuntos).
>   Ejemplo: si recibe las listas [1, 2, 1] y [2, 3, 2, 4], devolverá la lista[2].

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
def listas(a,b):
    lista_final=[]
    for i in a:
        for x in b:
            if i == b:
                lista_final.append(i)
    print (lista_final)

lista=[]
lista2=[]

i=0
while i == 0:
    num=int(input("Escribe una lista de numeros "))
    lista.append(num)
    a=str(input("Pulsa x si quieres acabar: "))
    if a == 'x':
        i=i+1
i=0
while i == 0:
    num2=int(input("Escribe una lista de numeros "))
    lista2.append(num2)
    a=str(input("Pulsa x si quieres acabar: "))
    if a == 'x':
        i=i+1

listas(lista,lista2)
```

Pero siempre obtengo una lista vacía y no se como continuar.

Comment: No sé cómo seguir.

Answer (score 1):

La idea principal la tienes, pero unas observaciones:

- La comparación `if i == b` debería ser en realidad `if i == x`. Con esto ya encontrarías solo los elementos comunes. Pero si que tendrás repeticiones debidas al `for` anidado, por cada elemento presente en ambas listas obtendrás `n * m` veces ese elemento en lista final (donde `n` es el número de veces que ese elemento aparece en la primera lista y `m` las que aparece en la segunda).
- Para evitar lo anterior debes comprobar por cada iteración que ese elemento no esté ya en la lista de resultados.
- Para saber si un elemento está en una lista en Python, lo más simple es que uses `in` en un condicional: `if elemento in lista:`. Como solo buscas los elementos comunes, basta con que iteres sobre una de las listas.

Con ello, tu código podría ser:

```
def listas(a, b):
    lista_final = []
    for i in a:
        if (i not in lista_final) and (i in b):
            lista_final.append(i)
    return lista_final
```

Ejemplo:

```
>>> lista = [1,2,3,2,4,5]
>>> lista2 = [7,2,5,8,10]
>>> res = listas(lista, lista2)
>>> print(res) 
[2, 5]
```

Por supuesto que en la vida "real" es un método extremadamente ineficiente comparado con la intersección de conjuntos ya implementada en Python usando tablas hash:

```
res = list(set(lista) & set(lista2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def intersection(l1,l2):
    l3 = []
    for i in l1:
        for j in l2:
           if i == j:
               l3.append(i)
    l3 = list(tuple(l3))
    return l3
```

Comment: Podrías agregar una explicación de lo que hace tu código?

Comment: Mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), así te das una idea de las normas de la comunidad para dar respuestas de calidad y evitar que sean eliminadas.